# TikZ diagram won't compile in classicthesis

Tags: tikz-pgf, classicthesis

Hello I am working using the classicthesis template by Andre Miede which can be downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home). Everything was flowing but I got an unexpected error while trying to include a Tikz graphic. This error states:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.128 \draw [arrows=<->, shorten >=3.5pt]
                                          (3.5,2) arc (0:45:1.5) node[midway...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I tried to compile this Tikz graphic in a different document using `scrreprt` class and calling the `classicthesis` package and it displayed the graphic without any warning.

The code of the Tikz graphic is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick, rounded corners=8pt] (1.74,1.5)-- (1.75, 2) --
(2,2.5)--(2.25,2)--(2.25,1.5);
\draw[thick] (1.5,1.5)-- (2.5,1.5);

\fill[pattern=north east lines] (1.5,1) rectangle (2.5,1.5);

\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};


\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (4,2);

\draw [thick, double distance=1.5mm] (2,2)--(4,4);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (2,2) circle (5pt) node[below,left,xshift=-0.2cm] {$A$};
\fill[thick, black] (2,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (4,4) circle (5pt) node[above,right,yshift=0.3cm] {$B$};
\fill[thick, black] (4,4)circle (2pt);

\draw [arrows=<->, shorten >=3.5pt] (3.5,2) arc (0:45:1.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I added this lines in the `classicthesis-config` texfile after calling the `classicthesis` package

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

Does anybody know what can be causing this behavior or any idea of how can it be fixed?
Sorry for not posting a MWE but the whole template needs to be downloaded.

**Edit** calling the tikz library `babel` I can compile my graphic but when I try to use it into a figure environment using the subfig packages options the same error shows up.

This is the code of the figure, by the way this compiles successfully in another document, I am using also `\usepackage{subfig}`

```
\begin{figure}
    \myfloatalign
    \subfloat[Coordenadas generalizadas de la barra $AB$, la cual se mueve en un solo plano.]
    {\label{fig:barraaba}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};

\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (2,1);
\draw[-,black] (4,4) -- (4,5);

\draw[-,black] (4,4) -- (5,4);

\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (4,2);

\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (1.6,2.4);
\draw[-,black] (4,4) -- (3.6,4.4);

\draw [thick, double distance=1.5mm] (2,2)--(4,4);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (2,2) circle (5pt) node[below,left,xshift=-0.1cm] {$A$};
\fill[thick, black] (2,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (4,4) circle (5pt) node[above,right,yshift=0.3cm] {$B$};
\fill[thick, black] (4,4)circle (2pt);

\draw[arrows=<->,black] (0,1.5) -- node[fill=white] {$x_A$} (2,1.5);
\draw[arrows=<->,black] (0,4.5) -- node[fill=white] {$x_B$} (4,4.5);

\draw[arrows=<->,black] (3.5,0) -- node[fill=white] {$y_B$} (3.5,2);
\draw[arrows=<->,black] (4.5,0) -- node[fill=white] {$y_B$} (4.5,4);

\draw [arrows=<->, shorten >=3.5pt] (3.5,2) arc (0:45:1.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$\theta$};

\draw[arrows=<->,black] (1.7,2.3) -- node[fill=white] {$r$} (3.7,4.3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
} \quad
\subfloat[La barra $AB$ posee tres grados de libertad por ser un cuerpo rígido en el plano.]
{\label{fig:barraabb}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};

\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (2,1);

\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (4,2);


\draw [thick, double distance=1.5mm] (2,2)--(4,4);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (2,2) circle (5pt) node[below,left,xshift=-0.1cm] {$A$};
\fill[thick, black] (2,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (4,4) circle (5pt) node[above,right,yshift=0.3cm] {$B$};
\fill[thick, black] (4,4)circle (2pt);

\draw[arrows=<->,black] (0,1.5) -- node[fill=white] {$x_A$} (2,1.5);
\draw[arrows=<->,black] (3.5,0) -- node[fill=white] {$y_B$} (3.5,2);

\draw [arrows=<->, shorten >=3.5pt] (3.5,2) arc (0:45:1.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$\theta$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
} \quad
\subfloat[Al fijar uno de los extremos de la barra $AB$ pierde dos grados de libertad.]
{\label{fig:barraabc}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick, rounded corners=8pt] (1.74,1.5)-- (1.75, 2) --
(2,2.5)--(2.25,2)--(2.25,1.5);
\draw[thick] (1.5,1.5)-- (2.5,1.5);

\fill[pattern=north east lines] (1.5,1) rectangle (2.5,1.5);

\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[arrows=->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};


\draw[-,black] (2,2) -- (4,2);

\draw [thick, double distance=1.5mm] (2,2)--(4,4);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (2,2) circle (5pt) node[below,left,xshift=-0.2cm] {$A$};
\fill[thick, black] (2,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw [thick, fill=white] (4,4) circle (5pt) node[above,right,yshift=0.3cm] {$B$};
\fill[thick, black] (4,4)circle (2pt);

\draw [arrows=<->, shorten >=3.5pt] (3.5,2) arc (0:45:1.5) node[midway,fill=white] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
}
\caption[Barra $AB$ con movimiento plano.]{Barra $AB$ con movimiento plano.}\label{fig:barrab}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you also try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`?

Comment: @percursse it worked out, but I am wondering why if that graphic didn't had text other than a few letters

Comment: I think you have a language that makes `<` and `>` active characters.

Comment: @percusse Now I am trying to include this graphic in a figure environment, more precisely using the subfloat package to make an array of three different images. The code compiles in another document but it displays the same error in the template, can you help me out? i´ll update the question with the code of the figure environment

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Use `subcaption` or better don't use `classicthesis`. It's often causing more trouble than it solves

Comment: `classicthesis` has nothing at all to do with the problem. The issue is due to using `babel` and not adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: @egreg I already called that library, but when I put the graphic in a figure enrivonment the problem persist

Comment: Can you make a complete example that demonstrates the problem? I.e. code starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, but containing only the parts needed to demonstrate the problem. (Might take some trial and error, but please try reducing it as much as possible.)